# Do I have to implement my own stack in swift? Does Swift have its stack in the library like Java?

Tags: swift, stack

New to Swift, so got confused when I wanted to use a Stack (data structure). Do I have to implement it by myself? If so, why doesn't Swift have it in the standard library like Java?

Comment: Implementation of it is demonstrated in the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Java, but if you need to be able to put items in a stack, and pop the last item off the stack, `Array`'s have the functionality:

```
var array = [1,2,3]
array.append(4)  //added an item to the stack
print(array)     // 1,2,3,4
let last = array.popLast()
print(last)     // 4
print(array)    // 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Stack<T> {

    private var stack: [T] = []

    mutating func push(_ item: T) {
        stack.append(item)
    }

    mutating func pop() -> T {
        return stack.removeLast()
    }

    func peek() -> T? {
        return stack.last
    }
}

var intStack: Stack<Int>()
intStack.push(1)
print("\(intStack.peek())") // -> 1
let first = intStack.pop() // -> 1
```